# If $M\cong M_1\oplus M_2$ is a torsion-free module, does it follow that $M_1$ is a torsion-free module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, direct-sum

Suppose $M$ is a module over some ring $R$ such that $M\cong M_1\oplus M_2$. If $M,\,M_2$ are both torsion-free modules, does it follow that $M_1$ is also? Intuitively I would expect this to be the case, for if $M_1$ had a torsion element, then surely that means $M$ would also?

Comment: There is also shown $Tor(M_1\oplus M_2)\cong Tor(M_1)\oplus Tor(M_2)$, see part $a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. If $m\in M_1$ were a torsion element, then $(m, 0)\in M$ would be one too.